# Prompting user to select pen color doesn't function

Tags: java

I'm supposed to prompt the user to select a pen color based on ones that I've picked out. I've already included an if, else if, else stamtement plus and .equalsignorecase, but whenever I run the file, it won't let me input anything?

(Also my variable "color" is defined as a string if that helps.)

Edit: I already have a scanner class embedded into my code. It's:

```
Scanner cool=new Scanner(system.in)
```

Hence any of my code that has "cool" in it is the name I've given my scanner.

```
System.out.println("Please enter the color that you wish to use to draw your point(color options: Red, blue, light blue, pink, green, orange, magenta, and yellow):");
color=cool.nextLine();

StdDraw.setPenRadius(0.05);
StdDraw.circle(2, 2, 4);

if ("red".equalsIgnoreCase(color))
{StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.RED);}

else if ("blue".equalsIgnoreCase(color))
{StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLUE);}

else if ("light blue".equalsIgnoreCase(color))
{StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BOOK_LIGHT_BLUE);}

else if ("pink".equalsIgnoreCase(color))
{StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.PINK);}

else if ("green".equalsIgnoreCase(color))
{StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.GREEN);}

else if ("orange".equalsIgnoreCase(color))
{StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.ORANGE);}

else if ("magenta".equalsIgnoreCase(color))
{StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.MAGENTA);}

else if ("yellow".equalsIgnoreCase(color))
{StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.YELLOW);}

else
{
   StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.CYAN);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `Scanner` to read the input. Try this out.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); // Reading from System.in
        System.out.println(
                "Please enter the color that you wish to use to draw your point(color options: Red, blue, light blue, pink, green, orange, magenta, and yellow):");
        String color = reader.nextLine(); // Scans the next token of the input as an string.

        System.out.println(color);
        // once finished
        reader.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: I already have a scanner placed into my code. I've named the scanner "cool" hence cool.nextLine();

Comment: It's still not letting me input a choice however, and I've included the portion of your code that's:

    system.out.println(color);

Comment: It should be `Scanner cool=new Scanner(System.in)` I noticed a lower case `system` in yours.

Comment: That wouldn't be the problem with the code since the one I have in my file this doesn't have the lower case system problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, it is supposed that you want to show what you have input. Below are some relevant input process:

You can use any of the following options based on the requirements.

> Scanner class

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = scan.next();
int i = scan.nextInt();
```

> BufferedReader and InputStreamReader classes

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String s = br.readLine();
int i = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

> DataInputStream class

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(System.in);
int i = dis.readInt();
```

The `readLine` method from the DataInputStream class has been deprecated. To get String value, you should use the previous solution with BufferedReader

> Console class

```
import java.io.Console;
Console console = System.console();
String s = console.readLine();
int i = Integer.parseInt(console.readLine());
```

Apparently, this method does not work well in some IDEs. The input you have taken can be printed / prompted by `System.out.println(input_object)` .